# Pause on image hover instead of empty area - HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with my CSS marquee, in which images move from right to left.
Right now the animation pauses when I hover anywhere inside the "SPAN", empty area or the images. I want the animation to pause on hover, only when hovering on an image; the animation should run normally when hovering on empty areas inside the "SPAN".

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="marqueecontainer">
    <div class="marquee">
        <span>
            <img src="images/upcoming01.png" alt="" />
            <img src="images/upcoming02.png" alt="" />
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.marqueecontainer {
    overflow: auto;
}

.marquee {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

    .marquee span {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 50%;
        animation: marquee 40s linear infinite;
    }

        .marquee span:hover {
            animation-play-state: paused;
        }

@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding classes to each image, like this:

```
<img class="pauseAnimation" src="images/upcoming01.png" alt="" />
<img class="pauseAnimation" src="images/upcoming02.png" alt="" />
```

and then to the CSS change it to

```
.pauseAnimation:hover {
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; /* Cross Browser Compatability */
   -moz-animation-play-state: paused; /* Cross Browser Compatability */
   -o-animation-play-state: paused; /* Cross Browser Compatability */
   animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Comment: ok. Thanks Timble, now its working as i want it. Thank you so much for your help! I appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to help and glad that it's working :) Please accept and vote up the answer if you can since it helped and was a solution, I would appreciate the rep. Anyways have a good day and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score -1):

Its quiet simple change this

```
.marquee span:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused
    }
```

To This

```
.marquee image:hover {
animation-play-state: paused
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeyentharaan, thanks for your answer but this is not working. Now the marquee does not pause when hovering anything.....

I have tried this as well but also not working:
    .marquee img:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused
    }